# Read pdf file with php-imagick on Travis

Tags: php, travis-ci, imagick

I need to read a pdf file on Travis with php-imagick extension.

I learned i need to adjust imagick policy.xml file to allow imagick to read pdf files.
So i added a custom policy.xml.

```
env:
  global:
     - MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH=$HOME/.config/ImageMagick/
...
before_script:
    # Allow imagemagick to read PDF files
    - echo $MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH
    - mkdir $MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH
    - echo '<policymap>' > $MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH/policy.xml
    - echo '<policy domain="coder" rights="read" pattern="PDF" />' >> $MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH/policy.xml
    - echo '</policymap>' >> $MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH/policy.xml
    - sudo rm /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

but still the build fails with `[Failed to read the file]`

The file is there, locally it works, i suspect that imagick still cant read PDFs.
The new policy also seems to be applied:

```
$convert -list policy

Path: /home/travis/.config/ImageMagick/policy.xml
  Policy: Coder
    rights: Read 
    pattern: PDF
  Policy: Coder
    rights: Read 
    pattern: PDF
Path: [built-in]
  Policy: Undefined
    rights: None
```

How can i fix this?

Failed build is: https://travis-ci.org/ivoba/silverstripe-simple-pdf-preview/jobs/563919021

Comment: With Imagick PHP uses a different sent of environment variables than the shell. So edit the delegates.xml file and put the full path to `gs` in the delegate lines that use it. GS is Ghostscript. Also be sure you have Ghostscript installed for ImageMagick to use.

Comment: yes i also found in the meantime that ghostscript was missing: `- sudo apt-get install -y ghostscript` made it work. feel free to place an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while i just answer my own question:

The problem was that imagemagick needs ghostscript for working with pdfs and ghostscript needs to be installed in Debian.

So additionally to editing the policy.xml file, adding the install command to .travis.yml did the trick.

```
sudo apt-get install -y ghostscript
```

Full working travis file is: https://github.com/ivoba/silverstripe-simple-pdf-preview/blob/master/.travis.yml

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it on a Standard Debian Environment. In my case Imagick was able to process PDFs without further do - Please ensure, that the Source PDF is in a non Adobe-Restricted Version e.g. PDF1.4. Otherwise it might not work:

```
$im = new \Imagick();
$im->setResolution(300, 300);
$im->readImage($path_of_pdf_file);
$im->writeImages($folder_to_place_each_page . '/' . $name, false)
```

Comment: Locally on Docker image php7.1-cli which is based on debian:buster-slim it works. So i guess its a travis issue?

Comment: Sorry - I got no experience on Travis - Just my guess, that it is indeed a Travis issue